# Writing to the database with $sql in a while loop

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I hope you will be able to help me with a php database problem.

------ here is the php file minus the database information -------------

```
// Connect to server and select database
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select database");

// read data
    $query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY ID ASC";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

// Start loop
$i=0;
$num=10;
while ($i < $num) {
$ID=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
$notes=mysql_result($result,$i,"notes");
$InStitches=mysql_result($result,$i,"InStitches");
$notes=mysql_result($result,$i,"notes");

echo"i=$i, ID=$ID | InStitches=$InStitches | notes=$notes";

if($notes=="In Stitches game"){
    // update data in mysql database 
    echo "<font color=\"#0000FF\"> || $ID yes ||</font>";
    $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET InStitches='yes' WHERE ID='$ID'";
    $ID2=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
    $InStitches2=mysql_result($result,$i,"InStitches");
    echo " || $ID2 $InStitches2 ||";
}

echo" - done<br/>";

// Increase value of i and continue loop
$i++;
}
```

---- Here are the trouble shooting results displayed on my monitor ---

```
i=0, ID=1 | InStitches=yes4 | notes=this is a note - done
i=1, ID=2 | InStitches=yes4 | notes= - done
i=2, ID=11 | InStitches= | notes= - done
i=3, ID=12 | InStitches= | notes=tester, In Stitches game - done
i=4, ID=14 | InStitches=22 | notes=In Stitches game || 14 yes || || 14 22 || - done
i=5, ID=15 | InStitches= | notes= - done
i=6, ID=16 | InStitches= | notes= - done
i=7, ID=17 | InStitches= | notes= - done
i=8, ID=18 | InStitches= | notes=blog tour winner, tester - done
i=9, ID=19 | InStitches= | notes=tester - done
```

---

For i=4 (ID=14)

The "InStitches" field is "22" and is to be changed to "yes" in the database.  But it does not change.  It stays 22.

I am using the $sql statement in other php files and it works just fine.  The only difference in this script is I have the $sql statement in a while loop.  So I searched and searched the internet to see if it was because I had the $sql statement in a while loop.  I could not find anywhere that it was the problem.  I have worked on this script for over 8 hours now and at my wits end.

Any idea why it is not writing to the database?

Comment: If you enter a loop to perform an action on a db, double check if you really need that loop. It could just be a set operation. In this case, rather than querying, then updating, it seems you should be able to do the update directly: UPDATE <table> SET InStitches='yes' WHERE $notes = 'In Stitches game'. Depending on the rdbms, use the RETURNING clause to return the fields of the updated columns you are interested in, or do a second query to get your results. Better one update then many in a loop.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the update statement!

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET InStitches='yes' WHERE ID='$ID'";
$ID2=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
```

should be

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET InStitches='yes' WHERE ID='$ID'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  Wow, an answer in less than five mins.  It works perfect now.  I can not say how much I appreciate your help!